# Can Table Storage PartitionKey be update?

Tags: azure, cloud, storage, partitioning, azure-table-storage

I'm using a Azure table storage in my project. I would like to update Entity's PartitionKey field. Is it possible to do this or should I remove the entity and add it again?

I thought it's not possible to update this field but the website description is confused me.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to update the PartitionKey (or RowKey) for a Table Storage Entity. You will need to create a new entity.

Instead of removing the entity and adding it again, I would recommend that you reverse that process i.e. add entity first and then remove the existing entity. That way if your delete operation fails, you still have the updated entity.